# java.lang.NullPointerException RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()

Tags: php, android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I use this firebase push notification in my code the notification message is coming but after that the app is unfortunately closed.Fatal error java.lang.NullPointerException RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference. How to overcome this error?

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //Calling method to generate notification
    /*if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }*/

    if (remoteMessage.getFrom() != null) {

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    } else {

        String SMessage = "Hello this is used for the testing";
        sendNotification(SMessage);
    }


}

//This method is only generating push notification
//It is same as we did in earlier posts
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SBTVerfyLogin.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notify)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your PHP code? It's probably that you're not including a value for the notification body in your payload.

Answer (score 1):

May be body is not present in your JSON. Make sure from PHP side that you sent body in notification. Probably you are sending message instead of body if this is the case please replace it with body.

Look at the changes in second JSON  as compare to 1st JSON. you will get your answer.

```
{
"to": "/topics/test",
"notification": {
    "title": "test",
    "message": "test",
    "image": "",
    "action": "",
    "action_destination": ""
}
}


{
"to": "/topics/test",
"notification": {
    "title": "test",
    "body": "test",
    "image": "",
    "action": "",
    "action_destination": ""
}
}
```

Comment: Hey @Noman, it would be helpful if you could be more specific about the changes by showing some code, or a link would also have been great.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())` twice.

Also, my recommendation is to check for `null` for `getBody()` and send. Avoid calling twice.